# UWP AppServiceConnection AppUnavailable

Tags: c#, uwp

Got AppServiceConnection like [This example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service) . It worked like a charm. But now, my app cannot connect to service, and returns AppUnavailable. Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not. I cannot simulate case, when it work. I really tried, but when it work, it goes very nice. When it does not, it cannot connect for days. (trying to connect every 10 seconds).

Apps are in one solution, that has multiple applications and multiple services shared cross apps.

What I observed:

- Sometimes it work, when I rebuild solution, but, sometimes it just not.
- I tried every step in example, with no luck.
- Best experience I have, when I clean and then Deploy whole solution.

Its nonsense, that I cannot run app, and sometimes I just do not get connection. Please, help me. I am total lost

Comment: This happened for me but it got fixed after I packaged both win32 to and uwp into a package project as shown in Microsoft site (give it a go)https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2018/07/29/packaging-a-uwp-application-with-a-win32-component-in-the-right-way/

Comment: Please add more information about your scenario. Are both client and server part of the same solution? Included in the same package or separate? UWP or Win32? etc.

Comment: Informations added, Now it works when i clean and deploy whole solution. But it take forever to deploy such a huge solution.